# How to enter ubuntu, why forget my gurb password?

Tags: ubuntu, users, grub2

I recently installed gurb, this tool allows me to customize my grub2, but when doing the customization I add password to the three different operating systems, the point is that I want to enter such systems but I do not accept the password and the user And I get a message that says "access denied", what I would like to do is break the security to be able to enter again to ubuntu and remove said key.

Comment: Do you have multiple physical disks on your computer? If so, I think it's possible to install a grub on the other one and boot from it. Then reinstall a grub from inside Ubuntu. UPDATE: also you can use live cd. Boot from it and then chroot to your Ubuntu installation. Then reinstall grub.

Comment: I only have one disk in the computer, but I have a removable disk, would it be possible to install the gurb from there?

Comment: see an update of my previous comment

Comment: And don't forget to use --purge when reinstalling to remove grub configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use rescue disk, boot with it.

When you are in the root of your rescue, mount your usual root (as e.g. /mnt) and chroot in /mnt. Then mount other partitions (/boot and /proc are needed by grub). There you can change the password and reinstall grub.